# Springboot - accessing MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have made a spring starter web project and need to connect it to a database.

In my pom.xml file, I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For my application.properties I have:

> ```
> spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/appname
>
> spring.datasource.username = root
>
> spring.datasource.password = password
>
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
>
> spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
>
> spring.jpa.show-sql = true
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
> ```

When I run the application, the server runs fine, however when I go to the URL localhost:8889/appname I simply get a page not found error.

Why is this?

Am I right in saying there's no need to download anything else (database server, for example) and it's all handled by Spring-Boot?

Comment: is localhost:8889/appname the url of you sql? It looks like you have a default setup and then the port should be 3001. Are you sure you have the right url?

Comment: Wait, `localhost:8889/appname` is *your JDBC* URL. The idea is then that you write some sort of Web application that uses the database.

Comment: I thought the spring.datasource.url created a way to access a new database  if one is not already there? It would appear I've missed some important steps. Could someone please guide me through these? The only guides I have found just say to add the maven dependencies and application.properties stuff....I require a complete guide. Thanks

Comment: You must have a database (in ur case MySql) up and running when you start your application. If you don't want to install MySql then try H2 or HSQL in-memory database, these will be downloaded and configured by spring itself. Check this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: Also, if you haven't changes defaults then you should be visiting http://localhost:8080/ which is default hostname and port no for Spring-boot apps. PS: I have a Spring-Data-Jpa Spring-Twitter example in my [Github](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/tree/dataJpa) repo using PostgreSql (more or less similar to MySql), if interested, have a look .